# getting oEmbed to work on my non-WordPress (static) website

Tags: oembed

I have a test page setup with several "oembed"-style links in different formats because I was trying to see what worked:
http://dev2.ohlone.edu/people/clambert/testoembed.html

None of them work. I have searched and searched Google and found nothing to indicate that I have to include a javascript file or anything else on the HTML page.

The server is running Apache on MS Windows Server. I do not manage the server and am unfamiliar with its setup.

This is a static web page - i.e., not generated using WordPress or any other CMS.

What am I missing?
Thank you,
-Cheryl Lambert
Web Designer, Ohlone College

Answer (score 0):

You have added links to oembed provider links in your html. To unfurl it and make visible the content in your html all you have to do is

- Invoke `oEmbed` api which you have added as a XML http request

you should do some thing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949969/get-youtube-oembed-json-with-ajax)

Then you could get response something like this

```html
<oembed>
 <type>photo</type>
 <flickr_type>photo</flickr_type>
 <title>Bacon Lollys</title>
 <author_name>‮‭‬bees‬</author_name>
 <author_url>https://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/</author_url>
 <width>1024</width>
 <height>768</height>
 <url>
  https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3040/2362225867_4a87ab8baf_b.jpg
 </url>
 <web_page>https://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2362225867/</web_page>
 <thumbnail_url>
  https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3040/2362225867_4a87ab8baf_q.jpg
 </thumbnail_url>
 <thumbnail_width>150</thumbnail_width>
 <thumbnail_height>150</thumbnail_height>
 <web_page_short_url>https://flic.kr/p/4AK2sc</web_page_short_url>
 <license>All Rights Reserved</license>
 <license_id>0</license_id>
 <html>
  <a data-flickr-embed="true" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/bees/2362225867/" title="Bacon Lollys by ‮‭‬bees‬, on Flickr"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3040/2362225867_4a87ab8baf_b.jpg" width="1024" height="768" alt="Bacon Lollys"></a><script async src="https://embedr.flickr.com/assets/client-code.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </html>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <cache_age>3600</cache_age>
 <provider_name>Flickr</provider_name>
 <provider_url>https://www.flickr.com/</provider_url>
</oembed>
```

Parse the response content and construct a `div` content which could contain

- File name
- Author name
- Provider name
- Description or
- Embed video content

And finally add the content to your HTML page.